# attempt to concatenate global 'gotoScene'

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I don't understand what I am doing wrong with ATOmap.lua ther is only image I do like with other file, composer.gotoScene("ATOmap" and so on but in the simulator gives an error in this line, when I change the way (gotoScene) all works good, i thought the problem with (-- activate multitouch) but why error in (gotoScene) line?

```
local mapButton = display.newImage ("images/mapButton.png", display.contentWidth / 2, display.contentHeight / 1.45);
local mapButtonTap = display.newRect(mapButton.x,mapButton.y,270,70);
mapButtonTap.alpha = 0
mapButtonTap.isHitTestable = true
mapButtonTap:addEventListener("tap", mapButtonTap);
function mapButtonTap:tap(e)
    composer.gotoScene("ATOmap",{
         effect = "crossFade",
        time = "250"
    })
end
```

Comment: Could you have an error in your ATOmap.lua file?

Comment: Maybe.. I am a novice in the corona) I'm trying to do That when you go to ATOmap.lua there is a picture and it could move and zoom in zoom out, but nothing comes out!

Comment: without seeing the code for ATOmap.lua or move of the error (found in your terminal/command window), its going to be hard to advise you.